# C++ Input Diamond Array

Tags: c++

i've had a problem with this code, it skips to 3 asterisks, and my desired program follows the asterisks in order. such as 1 to 2 to 3 asterisks and so on. I want the program to only accept numbers and not special characters.

```
                                                             *

                                                            **
  
                                                            ***

                                                           ****

                                                           *****

                                                           ****

                                                           ***

                                                            **

                                                            *
```

Example of desired output ^

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
 
  cout << "Enter a number: ";
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) {
      cout << " ";
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++) {
      cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) {
      cout << " ";
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++) {
      cout << "*";
    }

    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I input 5 for example, and the asterisks don't follow, it just skips to 3, for example, 1, 3, and so on.

Comment: It's your code, so I'll give you a chance to explain it. Where in your code do you control the number of asterisks that are printed? Look for an expression that represents "this is how many to print". Why should this expression evaluate to 2 when `i` is 2?

Comment: It wouldn't 'skip to three' if you replaced `j <= 2 * i - 1` with `j <= i`. This seems like a case of copying code without understanding the code you are copying. You are not going to learn very much doing that. Better to try and write your own code.

Comment: I gave an answer with a detailed explantion that reduces your 6 for loops to 1 and uses simple mathematics to count the number of characters. Please kindly check.

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you posted the desired output **and** the actual output. You have only posted the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me give you some explanation how to find a solution for this problem.

Let us break a big problem into smaller ones.

If we look at the number of asterisks, so, just at the characters, not at the identation or leading spaces, then we see for the input 5:

```
Row   Asterics   Number of asterics
 0                0
 1     *          1
 2     **         2
 3     ***        3  
 4     ****       4
 5     *****      5
 6     ****       4
 7     ***        3
 8     **         2
 9     *          1
10                0
```

So, we need a function, that will transform the row number to the number of asterics. And, we see a pattern, that looks like a pyramid or triangle.

And this will lead us to the triangular function. Please read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) about it. And in this kind of functions the "absolute value" plays a role. In C++ we can use `std::abs` for this.

Additionally, we can see, that the number of leading spaces to create a diamond is simply the given width minus the number of asterics, divided by 2.

With this know how we can now do the following simple calculation:

```
     Number of stars         leading blanks
Row  width-abs(row-width)    abs(row-width)/2 
 0             0                  5/2 = 2 
 1             1                  4/2 = 2
 2             2                  3/2 = 1 
 3             3                  2/2 = 1
 4             4                  1/2 = 0 
 5             5                  0/2 = 0
 6             4                  1/2 = 0       
 7             3                  2/2 = 0 
 8             2                  3/2 = 1
 9             1                  4/2 = 2  
10             0                  5/2 = 2
```

Additionally we can see the the number of rows is 2 times the width.

With all that, we can come up with a simple program that uses only one for loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // Get the max width of the pattern and perform a short input validation
    int maxWidth{};
    if ((std::cin >> maxWidth) and (maxWidth > 0)) {

        // The number of rows for the pattern is dependent on the width. It is a simple relation
        const int numberOfRows = 2 * maxWidth;

        // Show all rows
        for (int row = 1; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {

            // Use triangle formular to create star pattern
            const std::string starPattern(maxWidth - std::abs(row - maxWidth), '*');

            // Create leading spaces
            const std::string leadingSpaces(std::abs(row - maxWidth)/2, ' ');

            // Show output
            std::cout << leadingSpaces << starPattern << '\n';
        }
    }
    else std::cout << "\n*** Error: Invalid input\n\n";
}
```

Please note. For creating the strings, we use the its [constructor number 2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string). Here you can specify the `std::string`s length and the filling character.

---

And if you do not want to use strings, then you need to add again 2 `for` loops.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    // Get the max width of the pattern and perform a short input validation
    int maxWidth{};
    if ((std::cin >> maxWidth) and (maxWidth > 0)) {

        // The number of rows for the pattern is dependent on the width. It is a simple relation
        const int numberOfRows = 2 * maxWidth;

        // Show all rows
        for (int row = 1; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {

            // Calculate number of characters using the trinagular formular idea
            const int numberOfStars = maxWidth - std::abs(row - maxWidth);
            const int numberOfSpaces = std::abs(row - maxWidth) / 2;

            // print leading spaces
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSpaces; ++i)
                std::cout << ' ';

            // print stars
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; ++i)
                std::cout << '*';
            // Create new line
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
    else std::cout << "\n*** Error: Invalid input\n\n";
}
```

And, if you have even no `std::abs` the you can create such a function by yourself.

Then the code will be

```
#include <iostream>

int absValue(int v) {
    if (v < 0)  v = -v;
    return v;
}

int main() {
    // Get the max width of the pattern and perform a short input validation
    int maxWidth{};
    if ((std::cin >> maxWidth) and (maxWidth > 0)) {

        // The number of rows for the pattern is dependent on the width. It is a simple relation
        const int numberOfRows = 2 * maxWidth;

        // Show all rows
        for (int row = 1; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {

            // Calculate number of characters using the trinagular formular idea
            const int numberOfStars = maxWidth - absValue(row - maxWidth);
            const int numberOfSpaces = absValue(row - maxWidth) / 2;

            // print leading spaces
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSpaces; ++i)
                std::cout << ' ';

            // print stars
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; ++i)
                std::cout << '*';
            // Create new line
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
    else std::cout << "\n*** Error: Invalid input\n\n";
}
```

The output is the same as you have specified it. Please look for the last example with width 5:

[image]

And here with width 20:

[image]